# Argument cannot convert from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] to [current namespace].[wcf service reference].SqlParameter[]

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

My Visual Studio 2013 MVC4 C# Web project is calling a method in a WCF service hosted on IIS. The WCF method accepts System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] as one of its arguments. The call from the client passes an array variable to comply with this parameter. However, the client is returning the compile error:

> "Argument cannot convert from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] to [StateNumbers].[wcfStats].SqlParameter[]"

Where "StateNumbers" is the client and "StatsGets" is the WCF service reference.  Here is the WCF method (yes, it is in both the interface and implementation classes):

```
public bool GetStateNumbers(string StateProvinceCode, SqlParameter[] SqlParameters, out    string ReturnXML)
```

And this is the client call:

```
StatsGets.StatsGetsClient oStatsGets = new StatsGets.StatsGetsClient();
        SqlParameter[] parms = { new SqlParameter("@p_state_province_code", StateProvinceCode) };
        parms[0].SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar;
        string ReturnXml = "";
        bool bReturn = oStatsGets.GetStateNumbers(StateProvinceCode, parms, out ReturnXml);
```

Both the client and the WCF service have a "using System.Data.SqlClient" declaration. The client has the namespace "StateNumbers" and the WCF has the namespace "wcfStats".  The error I am getting reads:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]' to 'StateNumbers.StatsGets.SqlParameter[]'

Can anyone throw any light on what's wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your web service is declaring its own `SqlParameter` class. That's pretty ugly to start with to be honest... but if you *do* need to do that, you need to use it consistently.

Comment: Post the relevant interface (Datamember etc) definitions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The relevant interface definition in the WCF service is: [OperationContract]
bool GetStateNumbers(string StateProvinceCode, SqlParameter[] parms, out string ReturnXml);

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the idea, but I haven't declared any SqlParameter class, only a using statement for System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: @JohnP: Well look at the message: *something* has created a `StateNumbers.wcfStats.SqlParameter` class. I *very* strongly suspect it's part of your web service declaration. Look at the code that's been generated in the web service client. I don't know that it's even possible to pass `System.Data.SqlClient` values across a web service boundary. (What would you expect non-.NET clients to see?)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thank you, thank you, thank you, Jon. You are absolutely right. It was not the service declaration itself, but **of course** I should not be passing a non-native object (SqlParameter) to a service.  What was I thinking??? Problem solved!

Comment: Righto. In that case either you can just delete the question, or you can work out a good answer to it (how you actually solved the issue) as an answer.

Comment: The solution was to remove any non-native types from method arguments in the WCF service. In other words, the WCF methods should carry only native types, such as strings and integers. As @JonSkeet said, what would a non-.NET client expect to see? Certainly not a proprietary object like SqlParameter.